# Why do I get three times DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=10, random_state=0, splitter='random') in my list? Why is my for loop overwriting in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, parameters, classification, overwrite

I'm trying to write the following function where the function trains multiple instances of `base_estimator` on (X, y) where for each instance the parameter named `param_name` is set to a value from `param_vals`. Prints a message before training each instance. Returns the list of trained estimators. For example:

```
   >>> train_estimators(DecisionTreeClassifier(splitter='random', random_state=0),
                        X, y, 'max_depth', [1, 5, 10])

   Training DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=1, random_state=0, splitter='random')...
   Training DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=5, random_state=0, splitter='random')...
   Training DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=10, random_state=0, splitter='random')...

   [DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=1, random_state=0, splitter='random'),
    DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=5, random_state=0, splitter='random'),
    DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=10, random_state=0, splitter='random')]
```

I have the following:

```
def train_estimators(base_estimator, X, y, param_name, param_vals):
    
    list_of_estimators = []
    
    for param in param_vals:
        estimator = base_estimator
        kwargs = {param_name: param}
        estimator.set_params(**kwargs)
        estimator.fit(X, y)  
        list_of_estimators.append(estimator)
        print('Training ' + str(estimator))
    return list_of_estimators
```

However my output is when calling the following is:

```
>>> train_estimators(DecisionTreeClassifier(splitter='random', random_state=0),
                            X, y, 'max_depth', [1, 5, 10])

    Training DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=1, random_state=0, splitter='random')
    Training DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=5, random_state=0, splitter='random')
    Training DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=10, random_state=0, splitter='random')
    
 [DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=10, random_state=0, splitter='random'),
 DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=10, random_state=0, splitter='random'),
 DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=10, random_state=0, splitter='random')]
```

Why do I get three times DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=10, random_state=0, splitter='random')? I need the DecisionTreeClassifier that I printed, i.e. with max_depth=1, 5, and 10, in the list. Not three times max_depth=10. Who can help me?

Comment: You only have one estimator object, which you are repeatedly reconfiguring.  All of the references in `list_of_estimators` are to that one object; when you print the list, you are printing that object multiple times.

Comment: How do I solve this such that I don't repeatedly reconfiguring? I'm really lost :( I already placed estimator = base_estimator outside the for loop, but that didn't help

Comment: `estimator = base_estimator` is just giving another name to the existing object.  You either need to copy the object somehow, or make a new one for each iteration - I'm not familiar with the libraries you're using, so I can't give specific details on either option.

Comment: Thank you! That worked! I changed `estimator = base_estimator` to `estimator = copy.deepcopy(base_estimator)`